# Export registry value to file and then set a variable in Batch

Tags: batch-file, variables, registry

I am trying to export the registry value to a text file and then use it to set as a variable in batch.

For e.g. I want to find out what is the current sync location for One Drive folder, which resides in HKCU -> Environment - OneDrive (screenshot attached), then want to set a variable in batch for it.

[image: Here's where it is]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your registry key exists in that location then you don't need to do anything. Your location is already set for you!

```dos
Echo(%OneDrive%
```

Or

```dos
Set OneDrive
```